# Before I send my form, check if the maakartikel extends in my database

Tags: php, mysqli

My PHP Code:

I want that before I send my form it will check if the maakartikel extends in my database. If it already extends it has to give a error with: This maakartikel extends. If it doesn't it have to add it to the database.

```
 <?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "csa", "csa", "csa");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())

{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql= "INSERT INTO mart (Maakartikel, Omschrijving)

        VALUES 

        ('$_POST[maakartikel]', '$_POST[omschrijving]') ";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))

{
    die('Error:' . mysqli_errno($con));
}

echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: you want to check if `maakartikel` exists in your database, No insertion right ?

Comment: I have a form and you have to give a maakartikel. This maakartikel is about 8 numbers. And if this maakartikel already exist it have to give a error. If it don't it will add it in the database.

Comment: This code has a SQL injection vulnerability in it, always escape or parameterise your user input before using it.

Comment: Can someone just give me the code how to fix it? I need it quikly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
 <?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "csa", "csa", "csa");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// first check in databse befor to insert Maakartikel
$check_record = "SELECT * from mart where Maakartikel = '$_POST[maakartikel]'";
$query_execute = mysqli_query($check_record);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_execute);
if ($num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Error: This maakartikel extends";
    exit();
} else {

    //if not found in database then insert record.

    $sql = "INSERT INTO mart (Maakartikel, Omschrijving)

                     VALUES

                     ('$_POST[maakartikel]', '$_POST[omschrijving]') ";


    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        die('Error:' . mysqli_errno($con));
    }

    echo "1 record added";

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Zeeshan. There was only one mistake. $query_execute = mysqli_query($check_record); is wrong. It has to be $query_execute = mysqli_query($con, $check_record);

Answer (score 0):

try following solution

first write "select" query to check weather record exits or not 
if record exits then donot insert else insert data in table

for example

```
$select= mysql_query("select * from table where name='xyz'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($select)
if($count>1)
{
 echo "already exits";
}
else
{
 // insert record 
}
```

**Note : here i have used mysql functions not mysqli set so you can change whatever the functions regarding as dont know much of mysqli**

Answer (score 0):

Look into [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html). You can use this with your `insert` statement so it doesn't insert a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $check = "select maakartikel from your_table_name";
   $res   =  mysqli_query($check);
   if($res->rowCount() > 0){
   $sql= "INSERT INTO mart (Maakartikel, Omschrijving)

            VALUES 

            ('$_POST[maakartikel]', '$_POST[omschrijving]') ";

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))

    {
        die('Error:' . mysqli_errno($con));
    }

    echo "1 record added";
}else {
    echo "record already exist";
}
```